# The trait bound is not satisfied

Tags: rust

[Coroutine-rs](https://github.com/rustcc/coroutine-rs/blob/master/src/asymmetric.rs)

This is the function I am trying to call:

```
#[inline]
pub fn spawn<F>(f: F) -> Handle
    where F: FnOnce(&mut Coroutine) + Send + 'static
{
    Self::spawn_opts_impl(Box::new(f), Options::default())
}
```

I then created an enum because I actually want to send it from one thread to another, which is also why I have boxed the function. I have also matched the trait constraints.

```
enum Message {
    Task(Box<FnOnce(&mut Coroutine) + Send + 'static>),
}
```

But if I try to extract the function from a `Message`:

```
fn main(){
    let m = Message::Task(Box::new(|me| {
    }));
    let c = match m{
        Message::Task(f) => Coroutine::spawn(f)
    };
}
```

I get the following error:

```
src/main.rs:168:29: 168:45 error: the trait bound `for<'r> Box<for<'r> std::ops::FnOnce(&'r mut coroutine::asymmetric::Coroutine) + Send>: std::ops::FnOnce<(&'r mut coroutine::asymmetric::Coroutine,)>` is not satisfied [E0277]
src/main.rs:168         Message::Task(f) => Coroutine::spawn(f)
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:168:29: 168:45 help: run `rustc --explain E0277` to see a detailed explanation
src/main.rs:168:29: 168:45 help: the following implementations were found:
src/main.rs:168:29: 168:45 help:   <Box<std::boxed::FnBox<A, Output=R> + 'a> as std::ops::FnOnce<A>>
src/main.rs:168:29: 168:45 help:   <Box<std::boxed::FnBox<A, Output=R> + Send + 'a> as std::ops::FnOnce<A>>
src/main.rs:168:29: 168:45 note: required by `coroutine::asymmetric::Coroutine::spawn`
```

I have no idea what Rust is trying to tell me here. I assume that the problem is that `spawn` expects a non boxed function, but I get the same error if I try to deref the boxed function.

Note that at the time this question was asked, coroutine-rs doesn't build, and I fixed the errors in [this fork](https://github.com/MaikKlein/coroutine-rs).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's read the error message carefully:

```
src/main.rs:168:29: 168:45 error: the trait bound
    `for<'r>
         Box<
             for<'r> std::ops::FnOnce(
                 &'r mut coroutine::asymmetric::Coroutine
             ) + Send
         >:
     std::ops::FnOnce<
         (
             &'r mut coroutine::asymmetric::Coroutine,
         )>` is not satisfied [E0277]
```

Basically, you are trying to pass a `Box<FnOnce>` to a function that expects a type that implements `FnOnce`.

However, you cannot call a function that is in a `Box<FnOnce>`, because in order to call it, you need to pass `self` by value, which means that you need to dereference the `Box`, but that yields an unsized type, which cannot be passed by value (as of Rust 1.9).

The current workaround is to use the unstable [`FnBox`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/trait.FnBox.html) trait instead of `FnOnce`. `FnBox` is automatically implemented for all types that implement `FnOnce`. Here's how we can use it:

```
#![feature(fnbox)]

use std::boxed::FnBox;

enum Message {
    Task(Box<FnBox(&mut Coroutine) + Send + 'static>),
}

fn main() {
    let m = Message::Task(Box::new(|me: &mut Coroutine| {
    }));
    let c = match m {
        Message::Task(f) => Coroutine::spawn(|me| f.call_box((me,)))
    };
}
```

Note that the call to `Command::spawn` receives a closure that calls the `FnBox`, because we can't pass the `FnBox` directly to `Command::spawn` for the reasons mentioned above. Also, I had to explicitly annotate the argument type on the first closure, otherwise the compiler complained (`expected concrete lifetime, found bound lifetime parameter`, which I think is a bug in the compiler).

Comment: Thanks. Basically this means that I will have 2 function allocations and 2 functions calls right? Would it also be possible to extend `Coroutine` so that it also could accept a `Box<FnOnce>` instead of just `FnOnce`? And then I would not have to make the detour with FnBox?

Comment: Yes, there will be 2 function allocations, but the closure that calls the `FnBox` is allocated on the stack, so it's relatively cheap. Yes, there will be an additional function call. Also, `Coroutine` could probably be adapted, though you have a `Box<FnBox + Send>` and `Coroutine` currently deals with `Box<FnBox>`, which are incompatible.