# How do I pass a boxed closure to `take_while`?

Tags: iterator, rust, closures

The iterator method `take_while` takes as its argument a closure.

For example:

```
fn main() {
    let s = "hello!";
    let iter = s.chars();
    let s2 = iter.take_while(|x| *x != 'o').collect::<String>();
    //                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //                          closure

    println!("{}", s2);   // hell
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=947e01e338d5f508424771720f5cb9a7&version=stable&backtrace=0)

This is fine for simple closures, but if I want a more complicated predicate, I don't want to write it directly in the `take_while` argument. Rather, I would like to return the closure from a function.

I seem to be having trouble getting this to work. Here is my naive attempt:

```
fn clos(a: char) -> Box<Fn(char) -> bool> {
    Box::new(move |b| a != b)
}

fn main() {
    // println!("{}", clos('a')('b'));   // <-- true
    //                      ^--- Using the closure here is fine
    let s = "hello!";
    let mut iter = s.chars();
    let s2 = iter.take_while( clos('o') ).collect::<String>();
    //                           ^--- This causes lots of issues

    println!("{}", s2);
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1894cb14d1abfb88f9da819729af236a&version=nightly&backtrace=0)

However, the error that it causes has proven difficult to understand:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'r> Box<std::ops::Fn(char) -> bool>: std::ops::FnMut<(&'r char,)>` is not satisfied
  --> <anon>:11:23
   |
11 |         let s2 = iter.take_while( clos('o') ).collect::<String>();
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^ trait `for<'r> Box<std::ops::Fn(char) -> bool>: std::ops::FnMut<(&'r char,)>` not satisfied

error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'r> Box<std::ops::Fn(char) -> bool>: std::ops::FnOnce<(&'r char,)>` is not satisfied
  --> <anon>:11:23
   |
11 |         let s2 = iter.take_while( clos('o') ).collect::<String>();
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^ trait `for<'r> Box<std::ops::Fn(char) -> bool>: std::ops::FnOnce<(&'r char,)>` not satisfied
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
   = help:   <Box<std::boxed::FnBox<A, Output=R> + 'a> as std::ops::FnOnce<A>>
   = help:   <Box<std::boxed::FnBox<A, Output=R> + Send + 'a> as std::ops::FnOnce<A>>

error: no method named `collect` found for type `std::iter::TakeWhile<std::str::Chars<'_>, Box<std::ops::Fn(char) -> bool>>` in the current scope
  --> <anon>:11:47
   |
11 |         let s2 = iter.take_while( clos('o') ).collect::<String>();
   |                                               ^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `collect` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `Box<std::ops::Fn(char) -> bool> : std::ops::FnMut<(&char,)>`, `std::iter::TakeWhile<std::str::Chars<'_>, Box<std::ops::Fn(char) -> bool>> : std::iter::Iterator`

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
```

I have tried some other things, including using `FnBox`, but it didn't work. I haven't used closures that much, so I'd really like to understand what is going wrong, as well as how to fix it.

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779313/the-trait-bound-is-not-satisfied)

Answer (score 9):

There are two issues in your code.

First, [`take_while`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take_while) passes the value by reference to the function (notice the `&` in `where P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool`), whereas your closure expects to receive it by value.

```
fn clos(a: char) -> Box<Fn(&char) -> bool> {
    Box::new(move |&b| a != b)
}
```

Then there's the issue that `Box<Fn(&char) -> bool>` does not implement `FnMut(&char) -> bool`. If we look at the documentation for [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html), we'll see that the standard library provides these implementations:

```
impl<'a, A, F> FnMut<A> for &'a F where F: Fn<A> + ?Sized
impl<'a, A, F> FnMut<A> for &'a mut F where F: FnMut<A> + ?Sized
```

OK, so `FnMut` is implemented for references to implementations of `Fn`. We have an `Fn` trait object in our hands, and it implements `Fn`, so that's fine. We just need to turn the `Box<Fn>` into a `&Fn`. We first need to dereference the box, which produces an lvalue, then take a reference to this lvalue to produce a `&Fn`.

```
fn main() {
    let s = "hello!";
    let iter = s.chars();
    let s2 = iter.take_while(&*clos('o')).collect::<String>();
    println!("{}", s2);
}
```

Comment: This is one of those things in Rust that really does need more coverage. I myself have run in to this exact question about 10 times and still have trouble eyeballing a solution without a little bit of searching through documentation/forums.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I agree. I like learning Rust a lot, but things like this can take me hours to figure out (and then I might not even understand the solution). I know that they try really hard to keep the Rust errors very helpful, but the online documentation could be better. I guess that's a problem that all young languages have though.